# Edit Button: Conversion from string "name" in the datagrid view

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to edit a selected row from my Datagridview. When I try to change something in the textboxes, I get an error message for the first name and last name textboxes, stating: "Conversion from string "name" to type integer is not valid. If anyone could help me figure out what I'm doing wrong it would be greatly appreciated.

```
Dim dbo As New OwnersDataContext
Dim theowner As New Owners
Dim index As Integer

Private Sub DGV1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DGV1.CellContentClick
    index = e.RowIndex
    Dim selectedRow As DataGridViewRow

    selectedRow = DGV1.Rows(index)
    txtid.Text = selectedRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString
    txtfname.Text = selectedRow.Cells(1).Value.ToString
    txtlname.Text = selectedRow.Cells(2).Value.ToString
    txtaddress.Text = selectedRow.Cells(3).Value.ToString
    txtcity.Text = selectedRow.Cells(4).Value.ToString
    cbostates.SelectedItem = selectedRow.Cells(5).Value.ToString
    txtzipcode.Text = selectedRow.Cells(6).Value.ToString
End Sub

Private Sub btnEdit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEdit.Click
    If DGV1.SelectedRows.Count < 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Select owner")
    Else

            **If theowner.Update(txtid.Text, txtfname.Text, txtlname.Text, txtaddress.Text, txtcity.Text, CStr(cbostates.SelectedItem), txtzipcode.Text) = 0** Then
                MessageBox.Show("New Owner could not be saved to database. Please check input.")
            Else
                Me.Close()
                'refill the tbl with the updated
                Dim q = From o In dbo.Owners
                        Select o.Owner_ID, o.Owner_FirstName, o.Owner_LastName, o.Address, o.City, o.State, o.ZipCode
                DGV1.DataSource = q
            End If

    End If
End Sub
```

Added the update method from my class

```
 Public Function Update(ByVal pOwnerID As Integer, ByVal pfname As String, 
ByVal plname As String, ByVal pAddress As String, ByVal pCity As String, ByVal pState As String, ByVal pZipCode As Integer) As Integer

 Return mytableadapter.Update(pfname, plname, pAddress, pCity, pState, pZipCode, pOwnerID) > 0
 End Function
```

Comment: Somewhere in there you are trying to assign a string to an integer, or use a string where an integer is expected. When debugging, and before posting a debugging question, you should always temporarily remove any `Try/Catch` statements so that you can see and tell us exactly on what line an error occurs.

Comment: Sorry about that. I think I fixed my edit. I bolded where the error is taking place.

Comment: What is `theowner` and what is the definition of its `Update()` method?

Comment: I re-edited the code so you could see it. I called the  update method in my class .

Comment: I still need to see the that `Update()` method though, as it (or its code) is what's causing the error. The code you just added isn't relevant to the problem.

Comment: Public Function Update(ByVal pOwnerID As Integer, ByVal pfname As String, ByVal plname As String, ByVal pAddress As String, ByVal pCity As String, ByVal pState As String, ByVal pZipCode As Integer) As Integer
        Return mytableadapter.Update(pfname, plname, pAddress, pCity, pState, pZipCode, pOwnerID) > 0

    End Function

Comment: Please don't post long code snippets in comments. Even formatted (which yours is not) they are still hard to read. If you need to post code, edit your question and add it there, where it should be in the first place.

Comment: As for the issue, if there's a `String` being converted to an `Integer` on that line then it is an implicit conversion and that means that you must have `Option Strict Off`.  Turn it `On` and the compiler will immediately flag where you are passing data of the wrong type.  You can then address each of those issues with an appropriate cast or conversion.  It should be obvious then that you are somewhere using a name when a number is expected.  I suspect that your arguments to that `Update` method are in the wrong order but it should be obvious to you if you actually look at that method.

Comment: Actually, looking at the code you posted in your comment, both `pOwnerID` and `pZipCode` are declared as `Integer` and you are passing `Strings` to both parameters, so it's almost certainly one of those.  One of those `TextBoxes` appears to contain the text "name".  Maybe you should try validating your data before saving it.  That's why you use `Integer.TryParse` to convert text to an `Integer`: it validates and converts in one go.  `Option Strict On` forces you to convert and you can throw in the validation for good measure. Never assume a user will do the right thing; even yourself.

Comment: Also, the `Update` function you posted is declared as type `Integer` but it's returning a `Boolean`. `Option Strict On` will catch silliness like that too.  Data types are important.  They are not arbitrary.